# Reclaim unallocated partition on USB stick

Tags: audio, partitioning

I have a partition on my USB stick which Windows says is `Unallocated`.

When I right click on this partition, I do not get the option of creating
a new partition as all options are greyed out.

[image: Partitions]

What can I do to get this partition back and merge it with the existing partition?

I have access to both Windows 7 and a Mac if that helps.

Comment: Although I have put the answer I used below, I feel that is it not the most helpful answer that can be found as most people do not have a Mac as well as a PC.

Comment: I would use the GParted liveCD to repartition the USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reclaimed the entire USB stick by plugging it into the Mac and then used the `Disk Manager` to erase all of the data. This erased both partitions and created a new, single one.

Answer (score 1):

To me, I just plugged the USB stick on a Debian machine and used the Disk utility to delete all partitions and create a single one again.